# Can Dot Net MVC Application import an external sdk (javascript library for canvas framework in salesforce) salesforce

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, canvas, salesforce

Can Dot Net MVC Application import an external sdk (javascript library for canvas framework) salesforce provides and reference the same to decode the input request from Salesforce?

Example :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/sdk/js/canvas-all.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/json2.js"></script>
<script>
       Sfdc.canvas(function() {
            var sr = JSON.parse('<%=signedRequestJson%>');
// Save the token
            Sfdc.canvas.oauth.token(sr.oauthToken);
            Sfdc.canvas.byId('username').innerHTML = sr.context.user.fullName;
    Sfdc.canvas.byId('input').innerHTML = '<%=signedRequestJson%>';
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Short answer yes. As far as the application is concerned, the library is a resource that can be consumed and used. Its just like using js libraries via a cdn

Answer (score 0):

Sure that works. The salesforce JavaScript library can be included just as any other library with a `<script src="...">` tag.